# Xcode no archive after successful build

Tags: ios, xcode

Xcode 4.1 with iOS Development

Product -> Archive has always worked for me in the past.  But now that I changed away from a development provisioning profile to a distribution provisioning profile I get a "Successful Build" however no archive shows up in the Organizer.

Anyone run into anything similar?

Comment: Changing Target Build Setting -> Skip Install (Release) back to 'NO' allows for the archive.  Guess that means I have static libraries that are not being included in binary?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You've answered your question in your comment. If you have Static libraries being linked with your app, you need to set the "Skip Install" property on the static library projects to YES and set the property to NO in the project file of the App itself.

Answer (score 0):

For me, I had to also change the following blank build setting, to something like...

"Installation Directory"  -->  /Applications

Finally, it started appearing in Organizer/Archives.

Hope this helps somebody,

~Paul

P.S.  Interestingly, without this setting the old archive file was being created, but it was always empty.